# XJC generated namespaces 

Tags: java, namespaces, jaxb, xjc

I am trying to generate java source files from a package of *`*.xsd`* files using the **xjc** code generation tool.

The namespaces used in those *.xsd files are as follows:

```
http://www.domain.com/foo/bar.x  
http://www.domain.com/foo/bar.x.y  
http://www.domain.com/foo/bar.x.y.z
```

**XJC** produces packages as follows:

com.domain.foo.bar.x and places generated java files from "...x" and "...x.y" xsd namespaces there

com.domain.foo.bar.x_y and places generated java files from "...x.y.z" xsd namespaces there

What I would like to achieve here is proper:

```
com.domain.foo.bar.x  
com.domain.foo.bar.x.y  
com.domain.foo.bar.x.y.z package names
```

Is this somehow possible? Maybe using custom **JAXB** bindings? I've studied jaxb custom binding docs but I am not sure if it's possible.

Basically I would like **xjc** to treat both "/" and "." as package separators.

Any help appreciated.

Adalbert

Comment: I have managed to solve this problem partially by providing custom bindings for particular XSD files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `jaxb:package` customization:

```
<jaxb:bindings
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    jaxb:version="2.1">

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="com.domain.foo.bar.x.y.z"/>
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Alternatively you could rename you namespace into `http://www.domain.com/foo/bar/x/y/z`.